# Rails sort posts using param queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to be able to sort easily through the User model. So in the view, you might see a few options to sort. A choice of two radio buttons, one for popular and one for latest. To find the popular users (based on their followers count):

```
/people?sort=popular
```

Or you could select the other radio to just find the most recent users:

```
/people?sort=latest
```

Then from their you can select a checkbox (where you can select multiple) like `most posts` to find the users with the most posts and that are the most popular:

```
/people?sort=popular&posts=on
```

And another checkbox to find the user's that are contactable (which is a boolean value stored in the user's table)

```
 /people?sort=popular&posts=on&contactable=on
```

I hope this makes sense. Dribbble does this very well when you sort through their Designers. Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?? Thanks. Once I have a general understand on how to accomplish this I can add more options to sort as well. Also, I don't need AJAX so a page refresh each query is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails, every controller action has access to a params hash. A params hash has many things including a key/value structure for each item in the query string.

So in your `people#index` action, you will have the following available:

```
params[:sort] #=> value is "popular"
params[:posts] #=> value is  "on"
params[:contactable] #=> value is "on"
```

You can pass those as `where` clauses to your User model.